# Solving $a_{n+1} = x^{a_n}$ for various $x$

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, recurrence-relations, tetration, power-towers

> (a) Consider a sequence defined by $a_0=1$ and $a_{n+1}=(\sqrt2)^{a_n}$ . Prove that limit exists and find it.

> (b) Show that the limit doesn't exist finitely if we replace $\sqrt2$ by $1.5$. What are the maximum and minimum numbers such that limit exists?

I could do the first question and the first part of the second question.

For (a), by induction, each term of the sequence lies in $(1,2)$ and is therefore monotonically increasing by the recursion function. Hence the limit exists, let it be $l$, it comes $2$.

For (b), the sequence is monotone unbounded above, and the limit is $\infty$ similarly.

How do I do the second part of (b)?

Comment: Find out  why your proof of b works and try to replace $1.5$ by a smaller number.

Comment: Hint: if you plot different exponentials, you'll see that there are two intersections of the curves $t$ and $x^t$ which converge to one tangent intersection before they stop intersecting all together (as you modulate the value of $x$). How could you find the exact value of $x$ where a tangent intersection happens?

Comment: @NinadMunshi, I think that happens for $e^{\frac1e}$, since at that point $a^t=t$ and $a^t\log a=1$. Solving gives $a=e^{\frac1e}$ and $t=e$.

Comment: But that should be the maximum value, the infimum should be $1$??

Comment: Whoever downvoted it, you should justify that in comments.

Comment: @NinadMunshi, why don't you write that as an answer? I'll accept that.

Comment: Please state source.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From my comment, we want to find when a tangent intersection of the curves $t$ and $x^t$ will occur. This means we have to satisfy the following system of equations:

$$\begin{cases}t = x^t \\ 1 = \log x \cdot x^t\\ \end{cases}$$

with the added constraint that we are looking for the solution $x > 1$

Comment: I don't think we need the constraint. From second equation we get $\log x=1/t$. Taking log on both sides of the first equation and using that, gives us $\log t=1$. Subtituting back gives us $\log x=1/e$. Hence $x=e^{\frac1e}.$

Comment: And what is the infimum of all such numbers $x$??

Comment: @Martund I think you can graph different curves and gain an intuition as to what happens. The max is the harder one to figure out.